# Align the Logo of University on the top left of the the title page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, titles

I want to align the logo of the university on the top left of the title page with four lines of text on the right and I tried every possible solution available here like the mini page but it doesn't work for me. The logo appears on a separate page before the title page. I appreciate any help in this. My code is below. [image]  [image: here]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
total={170mm,257mm},
left=25mm,
right=25mm,
top=40mm,
bottom=40mm,
}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}
\usepackage{array,graphicx,lipsum}


\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\usepackage{titling}






\TOCLanguage{arabic} % arabic is the main language 
\newcommand\lr[1]{\textLR{#1}}
\newcommand\rl[1]{\textRL{#1}}


\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty\SAV@ps@plain}
\makeatletter
\pagestyle{plain}




\newcommand\numberstring[1]{%
\ifcase #1
% zero
\or الأول%
\or الثاني%
\or الثالث%
 \or الرابع%
 \or الخامس%
 \else I don't know%
 \fi
 }

 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\numberstring{\c@chapter}}
 \makeatother

 \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-3em}

  \usepackage{titletoc}%
  \titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
   [0pt]% <left>
  {\bfseries}% <above-code>
   {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel:\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
   \titlecontents{section}
                  [0pt]
                  {}
                  {\thecontentslabel {  } }
                  {}
                  {\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
    \titlecontents*{subsection}
                  [0pt]
                  {}
                  {\thecontentslabel{  }}
                  {}
                  {\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}



    \addto\captionsarabic{%
    \renewcommand\chaptername{المبحث}
     } 

    \addto{\captionsarabic}{\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{قائمة المحتويات}}

    \usepackage{titling}
    \newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
    \posttitle{%
     \par\end{center}
     \begin{center}\large#1 \end{center}
     \vskip0.5em}%
      }
     \newcommand{\subsubtitle}[1]{%
     \preauthor{%
     \begin{center}
     \large #1 \vskip0.5em
     \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
      }%
       }





      \newlength{\myspace}
       \setlength{\myspace}{10em}

        \makeatletter
        \xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vskip.5em}{\vskip\myspace}{}{}
        \makeatother


         \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}}

        \AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
         \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm\relax,-1.5cm){\makebox[0pt]                 [r]{\framebox{

   \\جمهورية العراق
   \\ وزارة التعليم العالي والبحث العلمي
   \\ الجامعة العراقية
   \\ كلية الادارة والاقتصاد
  
  
   }}}%
   }}



    \title{
    \Huge\textsc{دور نظم المعلومات في تحقيق رضا الزبون }
     }






     \subtitle
      {بحث مقدم الى مجلس كلية الادارة والاقتصاد-

      \\[3ex]اعداد الطالبة
      \\ ايمان رشيد حميد سويدان }

       \subsubtitle{باشراف}

       \author{ م. د وسن سعد عبد الجبار} 





       \begin{document}



       \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}


        \vspace*{1cm}
        \begin{center}


              \Large{دور نظم المعلومات في تحقيق رضا الزبون }

            \vspace{0.5cm}
              \large
              بحث مقدم الى مجلس كلية الادارة والاقتصاد-
        
      \vspace{1.5cm}
   
     اعداد الطالبة\\
     ايمان رشيد\\
     \vspace*{2cm}
      باشراف

      \textbf{وسن سعد}

       \vfill
   
       \vspace{1cm}
 
   
        ٢٥ نيسان ٢٠٢١
   
       \end{center}
   
        
       \end{center}
        \end{titlepage}
        %٪\maketitle

        \newpage


       \pagenumbering{Roman}
       \renewcommand{\thepage}{\protect\textLR{\Roman{page}}}

       \clearpage
       \setcounter{page}{1}



        \tableofcontents




          %\usepackage{titlesec}
         \titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
      {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}           {\Huge}   
         \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt}

         \pagenumbering{arabic}
         \renewcommand{\thepage}{\protect\textLR{\arabic{page}}}



         \begin{thebibliography}{99}


         \end{thebibliography}


         \end{document}


         %------------------------
```

Comment: For a single page, I would use `\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node[below right, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) {\includegrahics{...}};}`.  The tricky bit is if there is white space in the image itself.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put (0pt,0pt) {\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{...}}}`

Comment: This first solution keeps the same problem same, while the second one makes the first page empty, the image disappears.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the `background` package. With this you can add the image to the background of the titlepage, but make sure you set the background to "empty" again for the subsequent pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}

\title{My Title}
\author{My name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \backgroundsetup{
            scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1,
            contents={
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \node[inner sep=0cm,anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example}};
            \end{tikzpicture}}}
        \maketitle
    \end{titlepage}
    \newpage
    \backgroundsetup{scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1,contents={}}
    \section{Some Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if I do that the four lines of the text on the right jump to the next page.

Comment: Have you adjusted the margins in the `geometry` package to fit your use case? The background should not affect the text in any way.

Comment: yes, I did as shown above in the code.

Comment: It depends on where you put them (which is why I never use \maketitle).